# Android - after import module I'm getting an error on run time

Tags: android-studio, runtime-error, import-module

I've imported a module of [Image Picker](https://github.com/giljulio/android-multiple-image-picker).

On compile time it pass, but on run time it fail on error:
Error:(25, 35) error: package com.giljulio.imagepicker.ui does not exist

Why is that ?
Do I need to add any more information to the question ?

Comment: Try to sinc and clean/rebuild the project.
If the issue persists, post your build.gradle files and your settings.gradle

Comment: I've done what you suggest and still it happened.